# Proving $V$ is a simple $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, with basis $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$.  Let $GL(V)$ be the group of invertible linear transformations $\phi: V \to V$.  Define $\Phi: S_n \to GL(V)$ as follows.  For each $g\in S_n$, let $\Phi(g)$ be the (unique) linear transformation that maps $e_i$ to $e_j$ if and only if $g(i)=j$.

I proved that $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism. But I am having trouble proving followings

> Does $\Phi$ make $V$ into a simple $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$-module?
>
> For $g\in S_n$, what is the minimal polynomial of $\Phi(g)$?

For the first part of the question, I need to show every cyclic submodule generated by a nonzero element of $V$ equals $V$. And for the second part, I only have experience in calculating minimal polynomial on concrete examples like matrix with number entries. So it would be nice if someone can illustrate how to calculate minimal polynomial in more abstract setting.

Comment: IF it helps you visualize things, $\Phi(g)$ is the matrix of $1$s and $0$s obtained by applying the permutation $g$ to the rows of the identity matrix.

Comment: It is not simple, for example the vector $e_1+e_2+\dots+e_n$ is fixed under the action. I've written an answer about the decomposition into simple modules [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814319/what-is-the-dimension-of-this-space).

Comment: What does $\Phi(g)$ do to the vector $e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n$? For the second similarly think what happens to those basis vectors whose indices form a cycle of $g$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Does the fact that vector $e_1+e_2+\cdots+e_n$ is fixed under the action give a contradiction?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is minimal polynomial $x^2-x$?

Comment: @Sungn It means that it generates a (non-trivial) submodule, so $V$ is not simple.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Now I understand. Thanks. Can I ask you one more question? Is minimal polynomial $x^2-x$? I calculated it but not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Look at an example, say  a 3-cycle $(123)$. It permutes $e_1,e_2,e_3$. Can you see that the minimal polynomial of that linear transformation is $x^3-1$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes I do. The order of $S_n$ is $n!$. I am unsure how taking one example is beneficial. Can you explain little bit more?

Comment: Try it out with more permutations.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $(123)=x^3-1, (12): x^2-1, (1234)=x^4-1$. Thus one $n$-cycle gives minimal polynomial $x^n-1$. I also noticed that disjoint two equal length cycle gives minimal polynomial $x^n-1$; for example, $(12)(34)=x^2-1, (123)(456)=x^3-1$. But $(123)(45)=x^4+x^3-x-1$, which is disturbing.To give a minimal polynomial of $\Phi(g)$ I need to break down cases of $g$ and give minimal polynomial in each case. Am I right?  I am not sure the pattern of minimal polynomial when $g$ is a product of disjoint non equal length cycles.

Comment: Yes, that's what you should be seeing. You need the gcd of the minimal polynomials of the individual cycles. They all share $x-1$ as a common factor (in some cases others), and that shows in the minimal polynomial of $(123)(45)$ which is $(x^3-1)(x^2-1)/(x-1)$.